# How to get the cell at a location in pandas dataframe using a column as the index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

Example dataframe:

```
class   fred    bill
0   a   23  35
1   b   123 45
2   c   34  45
3   d   4   45
```

(pandas adds the index (0->3) which isn't needed)

What i want is to say something like:

```
fred_b_class = df.at['fred','b'] 
>>> 123
```

I tried setting the column `'class'` as the index by `pd.set_index('class')`

However when calling `df.index.name` it returned `none`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `class` and then swap arguments in [`at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html), because first argument is index and second column name:

```
df = df.set_index('class')
#df.set_index('class', inplace=True)
print (df)
       fred  bill
class            
a        23    35
b       123    45
c        34    45
d         4    45

print (df.at['b','fred'] )
123
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this solution, in case for some reason you do not intend to replace your existing index with dataframe column

```
df['fred'][df.class=='b']
```